# DatagridView: How to delete selected cells

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

There are number of questions on here about how to delete selected rows, but none about how to delete selected cells. That is, I would like for the user to be able to select cells from different rows and different columns, and be able to delete the contents. What I currenlty have is :

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
        {
            int rowIndex = cell.RowIndex;
            int colIndex = cell.ColumnIndex;
            dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[colIndex].Value = 0;
        }
    }
```

So the user has to select the required cells and then push the delete button(here I assumed all my columns are of numeric type, so 0 works). But it doesn't leave the cells completely empty. Here is another attempt:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
          if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected)
        {
           dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = null;
           e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately this event gets caught by my dataGridView1_DataError event, where I have

```
bindingSource1.CancelEdit();
```

And so I can't assign null to cell contents.

**Goal**

I would like to emulate the row delete behaviour, where you can select a row, push the **delete** key and then all cell contents of that row are left **blank**. I would like to do this, instead of leaving zeros in the cells. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following code:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
        {
            cell.Value = "";
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To hide the zeroes, try using the CellFormatting event:

```
void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Value != null && e.Value.ToString() != "" && (int)e.Value == 0) {
    e.Value = string.Empty;
    e.FormattingApplied = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I get an InvalidCastException on load up of my data

Comment: @Iason You said they are all integers.  If not, you have to account for that.

Comment: I think I need to change (int) to (double).

Comment: The code works with (double), but it deletes any cells that contain a 0 obviously on load up of data.

Comment: @Iason Then you need to store a flag somewhere to determine the difference between a loaded zero and a deleted zero.

Comment: Yes, this can work. However I would like for the user to be able to edit the cell, and put a 0 in it, without it hiding. Then another example, the user would select a cell, push the delete key for example, and the cell contents would completely dissappear.

Comment: @Iason Well, you only want to hide the zeroes when the user pressed the Delete button or key, so only set the flag in those circumstances, reset the flag for any other user edit.